# Catch useless comparisons like `===` when it should set a value with `=`

Tags: javascript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am entering quite a large project where there have been several times that developers wanted set a value like:

```
x = 10;
```

but instead used

```
x === 10;
```

I want an eslint rule that could catch this but so far have had no luck in my search.

Would anyone know a rule using preferably eslint or a plugin for eslint?

Comment: Shouldn't that be caught by some "useless expression without side effect" rule…?

Comment: _"...that developers wanted set a value like...but instead used..."_ - Are you sure about that? Using `===` instead of `=` doesn't seem that obvious, and the other way round is more common. Also that would produce a really different behavior/logic.

Comment: Both statements are valid js expressions, so why would eslint mark that ? It looks more like you need a code review process in order to catch those junior mistakes.

Comment: @LukeCelitan actually the second expression is valid, but does absolutely nothing. So it makes sense to mark this with ESLint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch this with [no-unused-expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-unused-expressions) ESLint rule.

```js
let x;
x = 0; // -> no error
x === 10; // -> ESLint: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.(no-unused-expressions)
```